# how to fix RCTTurboModuleManager.mm:307:13 No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

Tags: reactjs, swift, react-native

/Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/RetailC/axa-mobile/vidmedapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm:307:13 No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

how ro fix this ios /Users/dhanushraj/Desktop/RetailC/axa-mobile/vidmedapp/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/turbomodule/core/platform/ios/RCTTurboModuleManager.mm:307:13 No matching function for call to 'RCTBridgeModuleNameForClass'

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.